# consumir una api con vuejs y axios

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando intento hacer put me da un error 403 porque no autentico un usuario ya lo probe con postman y funciona siempre y cuando le pase el usuario

mi pregunta es como lo hago con axios ya que he probado de muchas formas y nada

Comment: Porfavor edita tu pregunta remplazando la imagen con el código escrito en texto, sino es muy complicado replicar tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar los datos de autenticación de la siguiente forma:

```
axios.put('/inventario/api/v1/products/1', {data: this.datos}, {
  auth: {
    username: username,
    password: password
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

aunque te sugiero:

```
var username = 'username';
var password = 'password';
var basicAuth = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);
axios.put('/inventario/api/v1/products/1', {data: this.datos}, {
  headers: { 'Authorization': + basicAuth }
}).then()
```

Revisa la documentación en https://github.com/axios/axios